# Using wildcards with nested generics in java

Tags: java, generics

I have a class that can a list of take both a generic `Number` and a `Double` to perform a certain calculation.

This works fine:

```
public class Test<T extends Number> {

    public void testGeneric(List<T> list){
        doTest(list);
    }

    public void testExplicit(List<Double> list){
        doTest(list);
    }

    public void doTest(List<? extends Number> testList){}

}
```

However, if the argument in question is a nested type, it doesn't compile anymore:

```
public class Test<T extends Number> {

    public void testGeneric(List<List<T>> list){
        doTest(list);
    }

    public void testExplicit(List<List<Double>> list){
        doTest(list);
    }

    public void doTest(List<List<? extends Number>> testList){}

}
```

Note that the functionality of the list doesn't matter, the second List type can be anything generic, for instance a wrapper around the T type. I don't really see why there should be any difference. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you apparently have realized, a `List<Double>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>`; you need the wildcards to make the inheritance "propagate" into the generic types: a `List<Double>` is a subtype of `List<? extends Number>`. However, the wildcards must go all the way from the outermost level: a `List<X>` is a subtype of `List<List<? extends Number>>` only if `X` is *exactly* a `List<? extends Number>`. If you want to accept other subtypes of `List<? extends Number>`, such as `List<Double>`, you need `List<? extends List<? extends Number>>`.